# Very odd open-drain output design

Tags: mosfet, transmission-line, current-limiting, fet, open-drain

I ran across a open-drain design and am baffled by the resistor between the nFET source and ground. There are only two purposes that I see it could serve.

1) It's series source termination, matching the impedance of a transmission line attached to the drain. However if this is the case, R would be better placed on the drain terminal.

2) Protection against a ground short in the event of an oxide breakdown shorting gate to source. Again, even in this case R would be better placed at the gate of the nFET.

Am I missing anything? The drain is indeed connected to a transmission line, and is pulled up by a 16V rail at the end of the cable run.

EDIT: I'll add that on the other end it's a high-Z digital input along with that 30k pullup to 16V. Also the buffer's supply is only 3v3, driving a low Vgs nFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZ4YZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Maybe intended to be protection against the output being shorted to a positive voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's designed to be a current source, not a hard pull-down. M1 acts as a source follower with R1 as the load. The IRF530 has a VT of 2-4V, so if the buffer is producing 16V, the output current would be around 150-170mA regardless of the pull-up voltage. The other end of the line could use current sensing to determine the state of the output.

That's as much as I can guess without knowing more about the rest of the system. What's connected on the other end of the line? What's the pull-up resistance? Is this a single-ended data line, or part of a differential pair?

EDIT: A low-VT transistor (which is more reasonable) being driven by a 3.3V buffer suggests a current of around 37mA. The weak pull-up would source 0.53mA at most. Since the input at the other end is high-impedance, that suggests to me that the goal of this circuit is to limit the slew rate. Instead of producing a very fast (and thus noisy) pull-down, the current sink gives a gradual rise whose rate depends on the line capacitance. This reduces the bandwidth of the signal.

For example, if the line capacitance is 100 pF:

$$\frac {dV} {dt} = \frac {i_{out}} {C_{line}} = \frac {37\ \mathrm{mA}}{100\ \mathrm{pF}} = 370\ \mathrm{\frac {V} {\mu s}}$$

$$t_{rise} \approx \frac {16\ \mathrm V} {370\ \mathrm {V/\mu s}} = 43.2\ \mathrm{ns}$$

$$BW \approx \frac {0.34} {t_{rise}} \approx \frac {0.34} {43.2\ \mathrm{ns}} \approx 7.87\ \mathrm {MHz}$$

The bandwidth is proportional to the current, so if your transistor can sink 500 mA, that would give you a bandwidth of over 100 MHz. It's not hard to radiate at that high a frequency! The formula I used for bandwidth is a rough approximation, so don't take it too seriously. The important thing is that a 10x difference in pull-down current can give you a 10x difference in bandwidth.

The weak pull-up is also interesting. It seems like the intent is for the line to stay low for a couple microseconds after it's pulled down. Based on the asymmetry, I suspect this is a reset or some kind of system-wide status signal, not a normal communications line.

Comment: Ah good point. I haven't worked with discrete transistors in a while. It's a single-ended discrete, pulled up to 16V by a 30k on the other end.

Comment: Looks like with the gate driven to only 3v3, and with an ultralow Vgs, we're looking at current limiting around 20mA. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Adam!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more speculation.

Comment: it's probably only an IRF530 because that's the default CircuitLab device for a N-channel MOSFET

Comment: Good reading for anyone else looking to brush-up on the topic. Thanks again for the insight Adam. http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/all-aboard-/4424573/Rule-of-Thumb--1--The-bandwidth-of-a-signal-from-its-rise-time